# How to solve extensions issues when restore PostgreSQL Database

Tags: postgresql, database-backups

I'm restoring a .sql Postgres dump on a database I created with

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database;
```

Later When I restore the database with

```
psql my_database < dump.sql
```

However, I encountered several errors which prevents me from restoring the data:

```
ERROR:  schema "pglogical" already exists
ALTER SCHEMA
CREATE EXTENSION
COMMENT
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/pglogical.control": No such file or directory
ERROR:  extension "pglogical" does not exist
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
ERROR:  extension "postgis" does not exist
ERROR:  function "order_sorting_weight" already exists with same argument types
ERROR:  type "public.geometry[]" does not exist
LINE 7:     viewer_locations public.geometry(Point,4326)[]
```

Following by repeatedly reporting:

```
ERROR:  relation "auth_permission_id_seq" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ALTER SEQUENCE
ERROR:  relation "auth_user" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  relation "auth_user_groups" already exists
ALTER TABLE
ERROR:  relation "auth_user_groups_id_seq" already exists
```

for each column of the db I guess.

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Drop or empty the database before you restore it. With `pg_restore`, you can use the options `-C -c`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried it several times plus that the dump file is of `.sql` type not `.dump` file, as `pg_restore -U postgres -c -d my_database -1 dump.sql`  works only on `.dump` format and throws `pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql` Error. and hence I have to use the above `psql my_database < dump.sql` command for this `.sql` format.

Comment: In that case you'll have to add `-C -c` to the `pg_dump` options.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you for you reply, however the dump files were not generated by me, All I got is them and I don't think that I can make any changes during the dumping process, any other solution please?

Comment: As I said, `DROP DATABASE` and then `CREATE DATABASE`. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem JUST by changing the version of posters I've been using, as I installed the latest version of Postgres (11.1), I couldn't restore the `.sql` dump files to it, and the dump file was getting dumped from a database server with version `9.5`. so I just uninstalled the whole Postgresql and installed the `9.5` version of it. I setup `pglogical` extension with help of [plogical-docs](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/) and now everything works just as I wanted.